# Way of saying 'washes hands of it' but implies physical

Tags: single-word-requests, writing, phrasing

Looking for a non-crappy way of describing someone doing that washing hand motion you do to clear your hands of dust or dirt, but without saying 'washing hand motion'.  I feel like there's a good way of describing it, a stock phrase of some kind, but I can't remember it.  Tip of the tongue, and it's driving me mad.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean running one's hands over each other, not when you're washing but when you are distressed or worried that's **wringing one's hands**

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wring-one%27s-hands

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit archaic but how about [Lave](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lave)?

e.g. She **laved** her hands.

> **Lave [*leyv*]**
>
> ***verb (used with object), laved, lav·ing.***
>
> 1.to wash; bathe.
>
> 2.(of a river, sea, etc.) to flow along, against, or past; wash.
>
> 3.Obsolete . to ladle; pour or dip with a ladle.
>
> **verb (*used without object*), laved, lav·ing.**
>
> 4.Archaic. to bathe.

Answer (score 0):

How about *rub/scrub/brush one's hands clean*?

> *He vigorously rubbed his hands clean under the sink water*.

Alternately, consider [**scrub up**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scrub).

> scrub up: (of a surgeon) to wash the hands and arms thoroughly before operating.